# RabbitMQ: basic ack takes very long time and blocks publishing

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using the Java Client 3.5.6 for RabbitMQ.

My use case is this:
I have 10-15 Channels to one queue (mostly the same connection, one connection per channel makes no difference).

I get them without `autoAck`. Every Channel has a prefetch / QoS size of 5000. So let's just assume i have 30 channels, so i can get 150000 messages.

Every full minute, i compute some things and when successful, i use `basicAck` to acknowledge these messages.

However, the management webinterface shows in that phase that 0 messages are delivered, which is not realistic unless those are somehow "blocked".

I'm using this queue on 3-node-cluster as a HA-queue with TTL set to 1800 seconds. The nodes are connected via internal LAN and the machines are really powerful with plenty RAM.

My Question:
Why does this basicAck operation block the rest of the operations like publishing or delivering new messages?

Comment: Check alarms - https://www.rabbitmq.com/alarms.html

Comment: Thanks! That leads me to the right path. I've also enabled "block notifications" in my producers / publishers. I'll see where this will take me.